# Passing data from one Java file to another in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am a newbie to Android development. I have two Java files in my project. One file contains my main activity so I want to transfer the data from one Java file to another which contains the main activity.

cordovaExample.java:

```
package org.apache.cordova.example;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.cordova.*;
public class cordovaExample extends DroidGap
{
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String phno = extras.getString("novel.PhoneNumber");
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),phno,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



}
}
```

novel.java

```
package org.apache.cordova.example;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class novel extends Activity
{ 
public String PhoneNumber;
Context mcontext;
public String getNumber()
{



 TelephonyManager tMgr=(TelephonyManager)mcontext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 

         Intent intent = new Intent(this, cordovaExample.class);
            intent.putExtra("novel.PhoneNumber", PhoneNumber);
                startActivity(intent);
               return PhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
        }

}
```

So i want to transfer the `"PhoneNumber"` from `novel.java` to `cordovaExample.java` but in `novel.java`, After running the application i am getting `"unfortunately app has stopped"` in emulator.

this is the logcat

```
08-12 15:49:37.657: E/AndroidRuntime(779): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-12 15:49:37.657: E/AndroidRuntime(779): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  ComponentInfo{org.apache.cordova.example/org.apache.cordova.example.cordovaExample}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-12 15:49:37.657: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
08-12 15:49:37.657: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
08-12 15:49:37.657: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
08-12 15:49:37.657: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
08-12 15:49:37.657: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-12 15:49:37.657: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-12 15:49:37.657: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-12 15:49:37.657: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-12 15:49:37.657: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-12 15:49:37.657: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-12 15:49:37.657: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-12 15:49:37.657: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-12 15:49:37.657: E/AndroidRuntime(779): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-12 15:49:37.657: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at org.apache.cordova.example.cordovaExample.onCreate(cordovaExample.java:20)
08-12 15:49:37.657: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
08-12 15:49:37.657: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
08-12 15:49:37.657: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
08-12 15:49:37.657: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  ... 11 more
```

Also, if I try the simple program I get the same result:

```
cordovaExample.java

package org.apache.cordova.example;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.cordova.*;
public class cordovaExample extends DroidGap
{
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

   novel c=new novel()
   int a=c.getNumber();
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),a,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



}
}
```

novel.java

```
package org.apache.cordova.example;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class novel extends Activity
{ 
public int a=0;
public int getNumber()
{

    a=5;

 return a;
        }

}
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You got `NullPointerException` at **Line20** in `cordovaExample`. The logcat told so:`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    08-12 15:49:37.657: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at org.apache.cordova.example.cordovaExample.onCreate(cordovaExample.java:20)
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android API guide contains a definitive FAQ item about [how to pass data between between Activities/Services within a single application](http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/framework.html#3).

try this,

do like this in novel to set the phone number

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(novel.this, cordovaExample.class);
myIntent.putExtra("phone", 989898989);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

in cordovaExample file do following to get the phoneNumber

```
Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String i = b.getString("phone");
```

if you are not able to pass the data then alternative way is to declare public method and pass them, see following example,

novel.java

```
private static String phoneNumber = "";

public void onCreate()
{
    ...
    phoneNumber = "9898989898";
    ...
}

public static String getPhoneNumber()
{
      return phoneNumber;
}
```

cordovaExample.java

```
private static String phoneNumber = ""; 

phoneNumber = novel.getPhoneNumber();
```

Comment: its showing "unfortunately application has stopped"in emulator

Comment: logcat is added to the question

Answer (score 1):

**you are using  intent statement after return block**

return PhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();

Intent myIntent = new Intent(novel.this, cordovaExample.class);

After return block any code show unreachable error .

**After passing intent parameter then you can call return.**

```
   TelephonyManager tMgr=(TelephonyManager)mcontext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 

   Intent intent = new Intent(this, cordovaExample.class);
   intent.putExtra("novel.PhoneNumber", PhoneNumber);
   startActivity(intent);
   return PhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

Comment: but now its showing "unfortunately application stopped" in emulator

Comment: Now I am updating the question

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this : You got NPE in `cordovaExample.java` becaus in `novel` you put `null` PhoneNumber in Extra.

```
     TelephonyManager tMgr=(TelephonyManager)mcontext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 

             Intent intent = new Intent(this, cordovaExample.class);
             PhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number(); // Check PhoneNumber  not null here before send to cordovaExample
if (PhoneNumber !=null ){
                intent.putExtra("novel.PhoneNumber", PhoneNumber);
                    startActivity(intent);}

            }
```

Comment: no its not null..when i write above code in the cordovaexample.java then it give the correct phonenumber but i want to put the code in the separate java file. also i tried to call it directly like this-- novel a=new novel() and then calling  string phno=a.getNumber()...then also it says application stoped

Comment: i don't understand `put the code in the separate java file` part

Comment: i have added the code...i have to make different java files for different methods